# How Do I Create a Popup Window?

Tags: popup

I would like to create a (read-only) popup window with some text in it, such that the user can close it by pressing 'q'. You know - the kind you see when you try compiling and get errors.

Any pointers to elisp functions I should look at?

Edit: I managed to get a popup buffer with the text I need, but I still need to make it read-only and respond to 'q' to kill the buffer.

Comment: Use `define-derived-mode` with `special-mode` as parent. Call the mode function for your newly defined mode in the buffer you created. That defines the right binding for the key `q` and makes the buffer read-only.

Comment: There are several ways to do what you describe. One place to start is with the Elisp manual, node [Temporary Displays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Temporary-Displays.html).